# Android display multiple dialogs

Tags: java, android

Despite its not best UX. I wonder what is the best solution to start several different Activity(Dialog) with different callback implementation. I assume starting each dialog needs to be from static fabric method with `context.startactivity(dialog1)`. Each dialog looks exactly the same besides some title and message but callback for `ok` and `cancel` buttons are different. I want to separate implementation of dialog callbacks(ok, cancel) from generic dialog behavior. What if I can't pass actions while starting activity from static method, I don't find Bundle to fit this case.

Answer (score 0):

How about this, create an enum for the dialogs.

Based on the enum you can either have the values for everything be in the enum itself or switch on the enum in your code at the appropriate places.

recommend creating different click listeners for the yes and no buttons.

In those click listeners you can switch(enum) and for each case have the specific business logic. OR create different click listeners and use a factory that will allocate the listeners based on the enum.

either solution works depending on how you want to code it. They both have their own pros and cons.

There is an AlertDialog.Builder class that you may be able to use depending on what your dialogs look like. There is also the dialogfragment class that you can extend to help out with the dialogs.

if you want to show the users several dialogs you will need some sort of queue that you populate with all the dialogs that you want to show and then show them one after another, IMHO, use different views and just replace the view in an activity so you can slide it in or animate it in somehow.

You can make them look like cards and then just change the text inbetween that way switching on the clicklisteners based on the type of the current view will be easy and you can even have the enums provide the views using the R.layout.layout_name as a value in the enum.

I know that is a lot and maybe some of it is unclear, Please ask questions and i will do my best to respond in a timely manner.